# Difference between Django ORM and mysql limit query

Tags: mysql, django

To get the 'n' records starting from row 's' mysql query will be something like:

```
select user_id from someTable where name = 'someName' limit s, n;
```

The same query in Django will be:

```
someTable.objects.filter(name=someName).values_list('user_id',flat=True)[s:s+n]
```

Now, the raw sql query will read and fetch just 'n' records, hence most probably will be faster if n is less.

However, in the case of Django, will it perform similar to mysql or will it read and fetch all the records and then will do a slice to give us 'n' records ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Django ORM makes efficient queries. It executes the query once you do something with the data (basicly said)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets

`someTable.objects.filter(name=someName)[s:s+n]`

will become something like:

```
SELECT name 
FROM someTable 
WHERE name = 'someName'
LIMIT s, n;
```

If you want to see for yourself, [there is a way](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running) to see which raw queries Django is executing. The [Django development toolbar](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/) is an efficient tool to do this